# Windows Phone Appx file fails upload for flight package

Tags: windows-phone, windows-dev-center

I am trying to setup a flight package for my windows phone application to deploy for Beta testing. When I attempt to upload the appx or appxupload file (doesn't matter which) it errors straight away. The progress dots continue and the caption says validating but at the end of the upload progress bar it just says 'Error'.

Any help with this issue is appreciated its driving me mad!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was an issue with the corporate firewall blocking the request. Would be nice to get a better error message though!